# Executenonquery requires an open and available connection. the connection current state is closed

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim response As MsgBoxResult
        response = MsgBox("Do you want to save the data ?", MsgBoxStyle.Question + MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "Confirm")
        If response = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
            Try
                Dim cm As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
                Dim cn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
                cm = New OleDb.OleDbCommand
                With cm
                    .Connection = cn
                    .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    .CommandText = "INSERT INTO Drug (DrugCode, DrugName, Branch Code, Branch Name, Dosage, UM, Quantity, Date, ConsPRN, EMPCode, EMPName, EMPPos) VALUES ('DCode', 'DName', 'BCode', 'BName')"

                    .Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("DCode", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 255, Me.DCode.Text))
                    .Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("DName", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 255, Me.DName.Text))
                    .Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("BCode", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 255, Me.BCode.Text))
                    .Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("BName", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 255, Me.BName.Text))


                    ' RUN THE COMMAND
                    cm.Parameters("DCode").Value = Me.DCode.Text
                    cm.Parameters("DName").Value = Me.DName.Text
                    cm.Parameters("BCode").Value = Me.BCode.Text
                    cm.Parameters("BName").Value = Me.BName.Text


                    cm.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    MsgBox("Record saved.", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
                    Me.DCode.Text = ""
                    Me.DName.Text = ""
                    Me.BCode.Text = ""
                    Me.BName.Text = ""
                    Exit Sub
                End With
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
            Finally
            End Try
            ' MsgBox("Unable to save data. Please input blank fields!", MsgBoxStyle.Question + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Error")
        ElseIf response = MsgBoxResult.No Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: What is unclear to you about the error message?  Your code never opens the connection.  Also Connection and Command objects should be disposed of when you are done with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a `cn.Open()` before your `cm.ExecuteNonQuery`, and then add a `cn.Close` before you exit sub

```
cm.Parameters("DCode").Value = Me.DCode.Text
cm.Parameters("DName").Value = Me.DName.Text
cm.Parameters("BCode").Value = Me.BCode.Text
cm.Parameters("BName").Value = Me.BName.Text
cn.Open() '<----- open the connection
cm.ExecuteNonQuery()
cn.Close() '<--- close the conenction
MsgBox("Record saved.", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
Me.DCode.Text = ""
Me.DName.Text = ""
Me.BCode.Text = ""
Me.BName.Text = ""
```

also, double check your `cn` oledb connection. It has no defined `Connection String`

Comment: Thank you Sir ! :)